# How to avoid large answer posts?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

Recently, I've been answering some [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) questions. Some users asking about this library usually are inexperienced in [sfml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sfml) or even programming in general.

I try to answer those questions by explaining everything, which causes me to **write very long posts**. Some examples:

- [Example 1 - Write text input on the screen in SFML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765163/3195314)
- [Example 2 - Why the texture appears only in the first quadrant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50370444/3195314)
- [Example 3 - Fractal Tree - branches not drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894496/3195314)
- [Example 4 - How to set fixed drawing speed and world steps in Box2D and SFML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54673456/3195314)
- [Example 5 - Is Photoshop “Motion Blur” possible with GLSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770697/3195314)

And I probably have some more...

**How can I avoid making my answers too long?** Would it be OK to include less code? Or fewer images? I like to include those because I think they make my answers more complete.

In some cases, I could just put links to some resources, but I've read that *link-only* answers are discouraged.

Comment: What's the point of showing a GIF of you running the code?  If someone wants to see what it looks like to run the code, they can just run it themselves.

Comment: Mis-quoting Blaise Pascal: "If I had more time, I would have written a shorter SO post".  They'll get appreciated, eventually, there are just not that many SO users that make the time to read it.

Comment: @Servy: Playing Devil's advocate - if I saw this answer on my phone on my way back from the office while riding the bus/train/ferry, it'd be enlightening and I'd have a better context immediately as opposed to waiting until I get an opportunity to make it back to my machine and compile the answer.

Comment: @Makoto And how is it going to be useful to you to have that information sooner, rather than waiting?  And how often is that actually happening?  How often are people looking for solutions to problems they're not actually in a position to use at the time?

Comment: @Servy before this goes down in a useless back-and-forth, we are not arguing if adding a GIF causes the answer to become not useful, right? In the sense that you're going to downvote such answers for having a GIF?

Comment: @Servy:  I often do browse Stack Overflow when I'm on public transportation.  If nothing else, it satisfies an immediate itch for knowledge in spite of the fact that I can't really *use* it at that instant in time.  If something catches my attention there's a stronger chance that I'll pull it up when I get back home and load it on my machine, which improves the likelihood of me actually compiling the code.  If I'm presented with *just* the code in this context, that's *fine* too, but not as attention-grabbing.

Comment: @Servy:  As I stated before, I'm merely playing Devil's advocate.  Images have limited use on a site which should be searchable, but in the context that they're not made the *primary* focus, I don't see the harm in them being used as something supplementary.

Comment: @rene Correct, we're not arguing that.  The question said that he believes his answers are too long, and asked for ways they could be improved by shortening it.  I pointed out what seemed to be a section of each answer that seemed to not be a valuable contribution to it, and proposed it be cut. You apparently think the answer is better with it than without it.  While I feel it lowers the quality of the answer, I don't think it outweighs the entirety of the value of the answer, making it overall not useful.

Comment: @Servy people always assume that if they can't get your example running on their system it is because there is a problem in your answer. It usually turns out to be a problem with their implementation or environment. Providing proof that your code does in-fact compile and run could be helpful to prevent such misunderstandings.

Comment: @TinyGiant Why do you think it's necessary to do that preemptively?  Are so many answers interpreted as not being compilable as they are?  It'd be way more effective to provide something like that in response to someone indicating they can't get it to compile.  And even if someone else *is* having trouble compiling it, you just having a picture to prove "it runs for me" still doesn't help them solve the problem of it not compiling for them.  If anything that's a sign that the code in the answer is incomplete, a problem not solved by such a picture.

Comment: @Servy: 100% of the coding I do is not for desktop or visual applications, so I wouldn't find the need to post a GIF, nor would the readers find much utility in it.  If I were working through a relatively complex Camel route and I could find a tool which *would* show data flowing between endpoints, *and* I found that to be a valuable addition to one of my answers, you *bet* I'd add that in.  Is that needed for all of my answers?  No.

Comment: I could even be agree with @Servy. Probably Tiny Giant catch my way of thinking. It's a preventing way of proving that my solution works, but the images sometimes doesn't make my answers more complete. Thank you all btw!

Comment: @Servy I use it sparingly but have done so where I think it supports an answer (and I feel they have value in the answers offered by the OP). And on most of my SEDE answers over on MSE you'll find a screenshot of the resultset which is admittingly useless after a week ...

Comment: Also such confusion tends to arise because I'm answering from the standpoint of a boilerplate example and a clean environment, where the OP's boilerplate may not actually be true boilerplate, or something in their environment is non-standard and is causing the problem.

Comment: [One of my longer answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35543715/2564301): a description of the source of the problem, six quotes with added commentary, and an (ulitmately inconclusive) test of myself. I would not want to cut it down anywhere.

Comment: Your answers read like anti-tutorials; they're dedicated and leave no stone unturned. That's exactly the kind of answers SO needs, IMO. Keep it up.

Comment: I am quite astonished with your question. Your answers are... Perfect. For the more unexperienced, even gifs are useful so they can see a result even if it is not working for them! So do not feel bother for writing long posts, if the answer requires it! They are really helpful!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your answers are long, true, but have a lot of breathing space, alternating between:

- explanation
- code snippet
- explanation
- code snippet
- image
- full working code so users can paste it and run it

Some may be annoyed by their tutorial-like style. I'm not.

Maybe images could be reduced & still readable, some noise like "I agree with @johndoe answer" should be removed as it's more like a comment, otherwise, they're not code dumps or "try this". Quality is visible at first sight.

Perfectly okay to me, and we need answerers in not so commonly mastered tags like SFML.

Answer (score 43):

I have no qualms with either the length or quality of your answers.  As an added bonus, it seems like the questions you're answering are on-topic and coherent and would be greatly satisfied from an answer like yours.

No one seems to really be *upset* about the length of your answers (except maybe the impatient, but they're not your concern), so don't worry about it.

You're doing *well*.  Keep it up!

<sup>Won't be upset if you elect to tamp on the brakes for answering though...</sup>

Comment: Certainly no one has complained about the answers. It's just me thinking about overwhelming the OP with a long (maybe boring) post.

Comment: @alseether:  Those would be "the Impatient" and they are not your concern.  An OP who couldn't read through an answer for comprehension isn't going to be fixed by a more terse answer.  Besides, I for one have no clue what any of the technology is being used (I know *some* C++ but only enough to know that it's C++), but I find myself somewhat enlightened with your answers.  You should take that as a badge of honor and not worry *as* much about this.

Comment: @Makoto I see tons of posts every day that are *less* comprehensible because of unnecessary content in the posts.  Obscuring the relevant information with irrelevant or tangential information can *absolutely* prevent people from understanding the answer who would have understood a more concise answer.  Now I'm not sufficiently knowledgeable about the topics the OP is asking about to say how much of the content in their answer is necessary vs. superfluous, but just saying "more is better, anyone who doesn't like it is just impatient" isn't a good writing style.

Comment: `except maybe the impatient`: TL;DR section may help.

Comment: @AmitJoshi - "_How can I avoid making my answers too long?_" - **Add another section!!!** ;D

Comment: @AmitJoshi -  *"TL;DR section may help."* - Sometimes.  Other times a comment to the nit-picker along the lines of "If you think you can write a better Answer, feel free to write one."

Answer (score 6):

It's not the length of an answer (*except if you exceed the limit, which you can do little about*) that matters, rather it's the quality and of often the intended audience.

If you believe that an answer is of good quality and that the length is warranted to provide the answer then rather than worry about the length of the answer take some delight in that you are one who is willing to go a little bit further to help others.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is really with the question if you end up needing to write a long answer.

One possible way to refactor this is to find - or create! - existing questions which explain subtopics in more detail.

So, instead of

> #### Lengthy Explanation of A
>
> A long and complex explanation of topic A
>
> #### Lengthy Explanation of B
>
> Another substantial diversion to understand complex subject B
>
> #### Lengthy Explanation of C
>
> Yet one more subsection which goes through the trouble of explaining C
>
> #### Finally Connecting the Dots
>
> Your real answer here.

you can then refactor to

> Briefly explain A with [a link to another question with more information](/#nonesvch).
>   Concisely summarize B with [another link to a more substantial treatment.](/#topicB)
>   Recap topic C and [link to a post about that.](/#topicC)
>
> Your real answer here.

This is obviously a substantial additional amount of work, but given what you are putting in already, it might well be worth the effort and save you from having to explain the same things several times in the future.

Posting "canonical" question / answer pairs is encouraged on Stack Overflow and if you have the knowledge and patience to build up a significant knowledge base about the basics of your particular field of interest, the rep payback could be handsome (but well deserved).

I'm not familiar enough with C++ or your library to tell if this is something you can straightforwardly apply, though.

Comment: I like the concept but probably is hard to apply this approach on my answers. Anyway, I'll take it into account before writing a long answer. +1!

Answer (score -13):

Perhaps not a **real** problem for your answers, but in general, avoid writing long answers by *not answering*, and instead voting to close the question as *Too Broad*.

Comment: None of the questions answered were too broad.  I admit that a long answer is typically the first sign of a problem but that's not the case here.

Comment: @Makoto That is why I wrote "not a real problem for your answers".

Comment: The answer here is just a bit too broad to really be that valuable.  You're painting questions with a very broad brush here in a circumstance that isn't all that applicable and it's *quite* misleading to an OP in this situation.  In general your advice isn't *bad*, but *specifically* for this case, it's horrible.

Comment: I think this answer is over-downvoted, I get the point. May not be this particular case, but if you have too much to explain, maybe is a *too broad* question. I never though about it, but I will have it in mind in the future.