# Posting bible-size answers might not properly help readers

Tags: discussion, answers, character-limit

I might be a lazy reader but I don't think bible size answers could properly help once you have to go through a thousands paragraphs to might understand the point and take what you need from it.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60307957/575643

*Such a big massive answer is really needed?*

Would be a nice rule/move to limit answers size?

IMO: Yes!

Comment: These are called canonical answers and YES we need them and this is the main purpose of SO. By the way, there is a limit in the answer size and I have reached it when writing this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333 (had to remove a part of it ...).

Comment: also such answer sallow us to close a lot of duplicate questions because they deal with a lot of aspects and can answer a lot of questions (some of my favorite dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/9289377/8620333) We need more of them!

Comment: If you do not want to read the post, don’t. If you do not consider it useful, you can even use your votes. No need to do anything else.

Comment: There is a length limit already: [The answer I'm writing exceeds the 30k maximum character limit; what should I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316012/7795130) However, you may want to exercise caution about the way you critique the length of an answer. If the critique is just "This answer has a lot of useful content, but what I want is buried under everything else," then I think it's the reader, not the answerer, with the issue. But if the critique is "This answer contains a lot of fluff that doesn't help anyone and distracts from the usefulness of the answer," then it can be helpful.

Comment: Related, but from the writer's perspective: [How to avoid large answer posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377807/7795130)

Comment: The only thing "wrong" I see with that answer is being surprised there already isn't a canonical answer for merge conflicts that the question should have been closed with instead of writing it.

Comment: Get off your duff and write the short one!

Comment: This post has been downvoted because bible size answers properly help and serve as canonical answers.

Comment: The things that really annoy me are those answers that are just too _medium-sized_. Like if there was a little more info, it would be "in-depth" and if there was a little less it would be "concise" but no, they couldn't just pick one. Disgusting.

Comment: On one hand you " don't think bible size answers could properly help" on other hand the answer you've linked to has ZERO downvotes (meaning that no one think that that answer could not properly help)... You may want to find an example that at least looks like it proves your case...

Comment: Some users are here to learn and to understand the solution to their problem. Just because you're not one of them doesn't mean the site shouldn't allow good and thorough answers.

Comment: *"a thousands paragraphs"* — Really?! The answer you link to doesn't even have two dozen paragraphs, depending on how you count much fewer. And they're all very short. Do you *want* to learn and understand or not?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just had a look at stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/8620333. Why did they have to put the important update partly making the answer outdated right at the end? It should probably be the first line.

Comment: @Trilarion that update concern only the last part that start with *justify-content: space-same (concept)* so it should not be at the start

Comment: Whenever I have a problem that's addressed by one of these "bible size" canonicals, I almost always find the solution I'm looking for there. That's the whole point of them, to comprehensively cover the problem.

Answer (score 38):

No.

Long answers are useful.

Comment: Dabble much in irony?

Answer (score 10):

The answer box already has a specified limit on the number of characters so you didn't make the news.

An answer like what you linked to doesn't come around everyday, so if you happen to come across an answer of this sort and you don't have the appetite to skim over it, then just move on.

Finally, as mentioned in the comments, we need this kind of answers because they provide a lot of insights and valuable information to the questioner and others alike.